# Query specific nodes from Firebase using Geofire?

Tags: swift, database, firebase, geofire

How's it going?

I have the following data structure in Firebase:

```
  reports  
   .XbCacF7tHosOZxxO(child generated by auto-id)  
     ..userId: "XvSjDkLsaA8Se"  
     ..message: "Text goes here"  
     ..latitude: "30.123131"  
     ..longitude: "50.3313131"

   .Yoa7HsgTuWm97oP(child generated by auto-id)  
     ..userId: "XvSjDkLsaA8Se"  
     ..message: "Text goes here 2"  
     ..latitude: "30.99999"  
     ..longitude: "50.99999"  

  users  
   .XvSjDkLsaA8Se  
     ..name: "John"  
     ..email: "john@email.com"
```

The idea of the app is that users can make multiple "reports".

In future if I have hundreds of "reports" I don't want it to overload my query. So I'm trying to find a way using Geofire query.

**My question is:** Is there any way of getting only the "reports" near me using the radius feature from Geofire and the latitude and longitude from "reports"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found a way of doing that.

I had to save my Geofire node "reports_locations" with the same id generated by Auto Id at the moment of the creation of the report.

The func that my app saves the data on Firebase:

```
//Save data to Firebase Database
let key = report.childByAutoId().key
report.child(key).setValue(dataToSaveInFirebase)

//Save data to Geofire node
let userLocal = database.child("reports_locations")
let geoRef = GeoFire(firebaseRef: userLocal)

let location = CLLocation(latitude: self.localUser.latitude, longitude: self.localUser.longitude)

geoRef?.setLocation(location, forKey: key)
```

I hope it can help other people.